# Haskell `forever` type signature

Tags: haskell, types, monads, type-signature

In Haskell why is type-signature of `forever`

```
forever :: Monad m => m a -> m b
```

Specifically why isn't it just `:: Monad m => m a -> m a`?
Surely the type of monad we are acting upon doesn't change half way through `forever`?

A function such as:

```
 forever' :: Monad m => m a -> m a
 forever' = forever
```

seems to work exactly the same.

Comment: The type of monad is `m` and it doesn't change. What changes is the result type `b`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The type signature of `forever` is crafted to suggest that its result runs forever. Specifically, there is no way to write an action of type `m b` (polymorphic in its return value) that terminates and yields a non-bottom value. An alternative way to suggest the same thing would be `forever' :: m a -> m Void`.

Another answer is to just say that this is the most general type available for the function as it's defined, so that's the one it was given.

```
Prelude> let forever m = let x = m >> x in x
Prelude> :t forever
forever :: Monad m => m a -> m b
```

These days, it probably should be defined differently:

```
forever :: Applicative f => f a -> f b
forever a = let x = a *> x in x
```