# ml function of type fn : 'a -> 'b

Tags: functional-programming, sml, ml, parametric-polymorphism

The function:

```
fn : 'a -> 'b
```

Now, are there any functions which can be defined and have this type?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit about what you are trying to do?

Comment: yes, what is the goal.

Comment: There is no such function that actually returns anything. (Try to construct a value of the type `Heffalump` that I just thought of.)

Answer (score 5):

There are two possible implementations for that function signature in Standard ML. One employs exceptions, the other recursion:

```
val raises : 'a -> 'b =
  fn a => raise Fail "some error";

(* Infinite looping; satisfies the type signature, *)
(* but won't ever produce anything.                *)
val rec loops : 'a -> 'b =
  fn a => loops a;
```

The first solution may be useful for defining a helper function, say `bug`, which saves a few key strokes:

```
fun bug msg = raise Fail ("BUG: " ^ msg);
```

The other solution may be useful for defining server loops or REPLs.

In the Basis library, `OS.Process.exit` is such a function that returns an unknown generic type `'a`:

```
- OS.Process.exit;
val it = fn : OS.Process.status -> 'a
```

A small echo REPL with type `val repl = fn : unit -> 'a`:

```
fun repl () =
  let
    val line = TextIO.inputLine TextIO.stdIn
  in
    case line of
      NONE        => OS.Process.exit OS.Process.failure
    | SOME ":q\n" => OS.Process.exit OS.Process.success
    | SOME line   => (TextIO.print line ; repl ())
  end
```

You might also find useful this [question about the type signature of Haskell's `forever` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170279/haskell-forever-type-signature).

Answer (score 2):

I can think of one example:

```
fun f a = raise Div;
```

Answer (score 2):

I can think of several:

1. One that is recursive,

   ```
   fun f x = f x
   ```
2. Any function that raises exceptions,

   ```
   fun f x = raise SomeExn
   ```
3. Any function that is mutually recursive, e.g.,

   ```
   fun f x = g x
   and g x = f x
   ```
4. Any function that uses casting (requires specific compiler support, below is for Moscow ML),

   ```
   fun f x = Obj.magic x
   ```

   Breaking the type system like this is probably cheating, but unlike all the other functions with this type, this function actually returns something. (In the simplest case, it's the identity function.)
5. A function that throws if the Collatz conjecture is false, recurses infinitely if true,

   ```
   fun f x =
       let fun loop (i : IntInf.int) =
               if collatz i
               then loop (i+1)
               else raise Collatz
       in loop 1 end
   ```

   which is really just a combination of the first two.
6. Any function that performs arbitrary I/O and recurses infinitely, e.g.

   ```
   fun f x = (print "Woohoo!"; f x)

   fun repl x =
       let val y = read ()
           val z = eval y
           val _ = print z
       in repl x end
   ```

One may argue that exceptions and infinite recursion represent the same theoretical value ⊥ (bottom) meaning "no result", although since you can catch exceptions and not infinitely recursive functions, you may also argue they're different.

If you restrict yourself to *pure* functions (e.g. no printing or exceptions) and only Standard ML (and not compiler-specific features) and you think of the mutually recursive cases as functionally equivalent in spite of their different recursion schemes, we're back to just `fun f x = f x`.

The reason why `fun f x = f x` has type *'a → 'b* is perhaps obvious: The type-inference algorithm assumes that the input type and the output type are *'a* and *'b* respectively and goes on to conclude the function's only constraint: That `f x`'s input type must be equal to `f x`'s input type, and that `f x`'s output type must be equal to `f x`'s output type, at which point the types *'a* and *'b* have not been specialized any further.