# 'a -> 'b function in ml

Tags: functional-programming, sml, type-signature

is it possible to write in sml/nj a function with the signature:

```
fn : 'a -> 'b
```

my initial purpose was to make a function with the signature:

```
fn: ( 'a -> 'b ) -> ( 'b -> 'a ) -> 'a -> 'b -> 'c
```

after many tries I got:

```
fn: ( 'a -> 'b ) -> ( 'b -> 'a ) -> 'a -> 'b -> 'c -> 'c
```

but I never succeeded to make as it was asked, and I realized that if it is possible for me to make a function from 'a to 'b I could find the solution.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [ml function of type fn : 'a -> 'b](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34912121/ml-function-of-type-fn-a-b).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only two possible implementations that give a `'a -> 'b` function, and they're rarely useful:

#### Throwing an Exception

```
- fun foo a = raise Fail "error";
val foo = fn : 'a -> 'b
```

#### Looping Indefinitely

```
- fun bar a = bar a;
val bar = fn : 'a -> 'b
```

I have a hunch that some details have been lost in the translation, because the second type signature you've given doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Which one doesn't make much sense?

Comment: @AdamElgressy `fn: ('a -> 'b) -> ('b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b -> 'c`. Not sure what would be the purpose of such a homework assignment.

Comment: anyway I used the looping Indefinitely approach and succeeded, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to write in sml/nj a function with the signature:
>
> ```
> fn : 'a -> 'b
> ```

Yes -- see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34912121/ml-function-of-type-fn-a-b) (and make it a habit of checking for duplicates as you ask. ;-)

> my initial purpose was to make a function with the signature:
>
> ```
> foo : ('a -> 'b) -> ('b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b -> 'c
> ```

It could be like this:

```
exception Done
fun foo f g x y _ = (f x; g y; raise Done)
```

Or like this:

```
fun foo f g x y _ =
    let fun inf () = inf ()
    in f x; g y; inf () end
```

What makes these functions similar to functions with type `'a -> 'b` is in fact the `'c` part, since this type does not relate to the input types, just like `'b` does not relate to `'a`. The `'a`s and `'b`s in `foo` actually serve a purpose and allow for some function application (`f x`, `g y`) even though these values cannot be a part of the result, since you have no type-safe way of transforming a value of type `'a` or `'b` into a value of type `'c`.

Comment: I looked for a similar question and I didn't find it, any tips as to how to find them better? To the point, I needed to get only 2 functions as a curry and then an 'a variable as a curry and then a 'b variable as a curry and only then to return a 'c variable. Anyway I found what you wrote helpful in understanding the 'a -> 'b functions phenomena in ml for me, so thank you for that

Comment: @AdamElgressy: You are right, this question is hard to search for because of all the weird symbols. I revised my answer to be a little more concrete.